# Modify SQLSataSource SelectParameters using JQuery or java scripts (VS 2013 C#)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Trying to incorporate ajax into aspx page, without using `UpdatePanel`.
When a particular Combobox index is changed, the resulting jQuery function needs to refresh the `SQLDataSource` object with new Parameters and then rebind it to feed another Combobox.
I cannot find any topic discussing this.

This is more or less what I am expecting, but was not successful in making it work:

```
$("#<%=SqlDataSource1.ClientID%>").SelectParameters(0).DefaultValue = 'aa';
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should write the ajax function which would bind your dropdown and call it on onchange event of the dropdown. An example of ajax function is written below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your method url',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: $.browser.msie ? "json" : undefined,
    data: { Param1: value1, Param2: value2 }, // in json format
    error: function (a, b, c) { },
    success: function (data) {
        // write the code to bind dropdown
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        // Show loading etc
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Have difficulty in undertanding the data: {} part compatability with the SQLDataSource.

Comment: @WBeetge: parameters added to data : {} which is in json format.